# how to change code this into recursion Java?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

```
public long weightedSum(int[] a, int[] b, int n) {
    long value = 0;
    long sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        value = a[i] * b[i];
        sum = sum + value;

    }

    return sum;
}
```

takes two 1D integer arrays and an integer n as parameters and returns the sum of products of the first n elements of the two arrays. For example, given the following two 1D arrays:

```
int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] arr2 = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

the first 4 elements of arr1 and arr2, that is,`1 * 6 + 2 * 7 + 3 * 8 + 4 * 9 = 80` as the result.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: why would you want to?

Comment: Compute `value` for the n-th pair and add to the result of recursing with n-1. Return 0 if n==0. (@ScaryWombat - because it is an assignment?)

Comment: because i want to learn the difference between loops and recursion Scary Wombat i want to know what i should change in that code and yes ted it is an assignment

Comment: This is not a good candidate for recursion since the algorithm is order N (your stack will overflow for large arrays). Try tackling factorial instead. (Still order N but given that 20! is the largest number you can evaluate using a 64 bit type, this limits things). Or, better still, a pivoting sorting algorithm or search on an ordered list. (Order log(N) so you're stack will be fine). If this is an assignment then point this out to your professor!

Comment: I really think the questions you are asking are HOLDING YOU BACK from learning this properly. We all get stuck and need help, but your questions don't add up . This one for example is not a good candidate at all for recursion. You wouldn't is the answer. Really you need to ATTEMPT IT YOURSELF first, then come with more **specific** questions. If people do it for you, as someone has, you'll never learn it correctly. I know this from personal experience, got too much help and I missed out on really, properly understanding it. For your own sake, attempt your homework first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static long weightedSum(int[] a, int[] b, int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return a[n - 1] * b[n - 1] + weightedSum(a, b, n - 1);
}
```

Output :

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] arr2 = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

System.out.println(weightedSum(arr1, arr2, 1));  // output : 6
System.out.println(weightedSum(arr1, arr2, 2));  // output : 20
System.out.println(weightedSum(arr1, arr2, 3));  // output : 44
System.out.println(weightedSum(arr1, arr2, 4));  // output : 80
System.out.println(weightedSum(arr1, arr2, 5));  // output : 130
```

Comment: thank u so much :) i am really thankful to u

Answer (score 0):

Her is an example solution for your problem:

```
public static long recusiveWeightedSum(int [] a ,int [] b, int index)
    {
        if (index == a.length) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return a[index] * b[index] + recusiveWeightedSum(a, b, index + 1);
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] arr2 = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

        System.out.println("Sum1:" + Sample.weightedSum(arr1, arr2));
        System.out.println("Sum2:" + Sample.recusiveWeightedSum(arr1, arr2, 0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres one I've done but you have to pass in 0 as n the first time you call it.

```
public long sum(int[] a, int[] b, int n){


        while(a.length != 1){
            return sum(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, a.length-1), 
                       Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 0, a.length-1),
                       a[a.length-1]*b[b.length-1] + n);
        }

        return a[0] * b[0] + n;
    }
```

Comment: Your welcome. However, like the others have said, your original solution is better (and don't bother asking for n as an argument because it then isn't used)

Comment: roger sir i will do that :) may god bless you